# Steganography -unhide methods

Tags: steganography

I'm trying to unhide information in a .bmp image using the tools on https://incoherency.co.uk/image-steganography/#unhide

However all I can see when using the tools are at best a black image with a few colored squares at the bottom and at worst a slightly blurry version of the image I'm using.

I've tried to use other tools but they don't appear to like .bmp files.

Are there any other methods to detect this? (that would be as easy as this site is supposed to be)

Comment: The linked tool works with .bmp files _made using the encoding convention that it uses_, then converted to bmp (and I believe even if not 200x200). It's not like steganography has a single encoding method!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unhide a random message you need your own proper tools.

If you want to unhide a message sent to you then you need to use the tools that the sender used.

Expecting random tools to work on a random message is nonsense even if you might get lucky once.